# Reverse Integer Values

Tags: mouse, logic, coordinate-systems

I have a scenario which I think I can convey giving PC Monitor example (not real though).

Assume I have two monitors both of different resolution and properties. One monitor draws mouse cursor on screen from top (0) to bottom (max-value) and other draws mouse from bottom (0) to top (max-value). In other words both have reverse y-axis of each other in drawing mouse cursor and I need to write a formula that will convert one monitor cursor position to another and vice versa given one monitor x and y cursor positions.

What formula is the best suited for this?

Comment: You need to convert so that the mouse cursor is in the same position in both monitors? Or what is the condition?

Comment: yes but both monitors are of different inches, 21, and 27 so you know what do I mean

Comment: it might be easiest to just use the OS to change the resolutions to match.

Comment: Thanks for you help guys, I would like to tell you that this question was imaginary to answer some other questions and it really helped in solving the problem. I am bound by NDA that's why it needed to be different question than what I should really ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
right_x = (1 - left_x / left_width) * right_width
right_y = (1 - left_y / left_height) * right_height
```

The `left_x` and `left_y` (as well as the resolutions for each display) would need to be known.